# Slow Range Based Queries in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, sharding, bigdata

I am using MongoDb 3.2 and have a data set size of 90 Million where the document structure consists of :

```
_id
eventReceivedDateTime(Date)
systemName(String)
triggerName(String)
eventStatus (Enum with 4 possible values)
```

Queries to be performed are :

1) Range Based Queries involving `eventStatus` & `eventReceivedDateTime` like :

```
db.event_record.find({
    "eventStatus": "SENT",
    "eventReceivedDateTime": {
        "$gt": ISODate("2016-04-19T23:46:30.827Z"),
        "$lt": ISODate("2016-04-21T14:18:30.827Z")
    }
}).count();
```

2) Range Based Queries involving `eventStatus` & `eventReceivedDateTime` and `_id` and involving sort. (For Pagination), like:

```
db.event_record.find({
    "eventStatus": "SENT",
    "eventReceivedDateTime": {
        "$gt": ISODate("2016-04-19T23:46:30.827Z"),
        "$lt": ISODate("2016-04-21T07:18:30.827Z")
    },
    "_id": {
        "$gt": ObjectId("57173a67e4b09ca56feddddf")
    }
}).sort({"_id":1}).limit(10);
```

3) Range Based Queries involving `eventStatus`, `eventReceivedDateTime`, `systemName` and `triggerName` like:

```
db.event_record.find({
    "eventStatus":"SENT",
    "eventReceivedDateTime": {
        "$gt": ISODate("2016-04-19T23:46:30.827Z"),
        "$lt": ISODate("2016-04-21T07:18:30.827Z")
    },
    "systemName": "OMS",
    "triggerName": "COD_ORDER"
}).count();
```

4) Range Based Queries involving `eventStatus`, `eventReceivedDateTime`, `systemName`, `triggerName` and `_id` and involving sort. (For Pagination), like:

```
db.event_record.find({
    "eventStatus": "SENT",
    "eventReceivedDateTime": {
        "$gt": ISODate("2016-04-19T23:46:30.827Z"),
        "$lt": ISODate("2016-04-21T07:18:30.827Z")
     },
     "systemName": "OMS",
     "triggerName": "COD_ORDER",
     "_id": {
          "$gt":ObjectId("57173a67e4b09ca56feddcd6")
     }
}).sort({"_id":1}).limit(10);
```

Every day about 3 million documents will be inserted and deleted.

I have the made following Compound Indexes :

```
{'eventStatus':1,'eventReceivedDateTime':1,'_id':1}
{'eventStatus':1,'systemName':1,'triggerName':1,'eventReceivedDateTime':1}
{'eventStatus':1,'systemName':1,'triggerName':1,'eventReceivedDateTime':1,'_id':1}
```

I am using 3 Shard Instances on same machine with shardkey :

```
{'eventStatus':1,'eventReceivedDateTime':1}
```

With these configurations, I am getting slow results for the above queries. Please suggest how to optimise/improve the query time.

Edit :

Shard Machine Specifications :

```
Cores: 32
RAM:  128g
HD:   160G
```

Storage engine is wiredTiger

explain() for the query can be found at this [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1W713YGdKRxSDQwRDNyNFVmbjg).

Comment: 1. could you show us explain execution stats dump `db.col.query.explain("executionStats")` 2. what kind of hardware/system specs you have? 3. what storage engine is in use?

Comment: @profesor79 I have added the information.

Comment: one more question what is the processor clock?

Answer (score 0):

in this case as you have all shards running on one system

> "shardName" : "shard0000","connectionString" : "localhost:27012",
>
> "shardName" : "shard0001","connectionString" : "localhost:27013",
>
> "shardName" : "shard0002","connectionString" : "localhost:27014",

it will be better to avoid using sharding as they are fighting for system resources.